# output list of special letters string with python

Tags: python, list, io, special-characters

I have 2 lists of strings, they are constructed from database content but I have difficulty in reading it into a txt file

```
list_a={u'XYZ-123-456',u'XYZ-123-456',u'XYZ-789-456',....}

list_b={u'Tom \n is creative', u'Sky is blue',....}
```

What I need to do is get rid of 'u' at the beginning of each string in both lists, getting rid of \n within each string in list_b where applicable.

then write each element in list_b to a text file, one by a line, into the txt file, whose title is the element in list_a.  Strings with the same title should be in the same txt file. Anyone can help ?

I think I can use pop function to get rid of u, but how about the '\n' within the string? 
I am also not 100% sure about the I/O function. Anyone can help me out with the sample script?

Thanks a lot, a newbie of python

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245561/request-python-code-for-editing-and-combining-files#comment19766371_14245561).

Comment: @thg435 -- was it really that annoying? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome so SO.

`list_a` is actually a `set`. The `{}` indicates `set`, which is a list of unique items - so you may not want this type if you expect multiple values in the 'list'. If you want an actual list then encapsulate the 'list' with `[...]` instead of `{...}`

The 'u' in the set indicates the text is unicode. if you want this removed:

```
list_a = map(str, list_a)
```

`\n` is a control character indicating a new line. This will be represented as a new line when printed in the console. If you really don't want new lines then do:

```
list_b= { item.replace('\n','') for item in list_b }
```

I assume you want each item on a new line in the text file. If so:

```
with open('c:\file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(list_a)) 
    file.write('\n'.join(list_b))
```

for non duplicates merge the 2 lists into a set. As they are currently already sets this will work:

```
with open('c:\file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(list_a + list_b))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a little confused about your code for I/O new line part: how can you ensure the elements in list_b with same title in list_a can be written in the same text file?

Comment: file.write('\n'.join(list_b))  - added to comment

Comment: OK, I see your point. But will this create duplicate titles in the document? Also, it does not involve a loop to write multiple files? guess I should add a outermost loop

Comment: to merge sets together just do set_a + set_b. I have shown an example in the post

Comment: Hi rikAtee, again thanks for your comment. I have successfully remove 'u' using your method for list_a, but for list_b, I got the following error:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: never mind, it is related to unicode in my strings, I will fix it